# field value in firestore document increments by wrong number due to print statement repeating 4 times

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-cloud-firestore, completionhandler

So my goal is to always have a proper increment value when a ticket is purchased. I'm having a strange bug where when I update a field value by incrementing it, it increments by the wrong number the first time every time I run a fresh new simulation due to the repeats in print statements, but if I was to update the value again in the same fresh simulation, it will increment by the proper value every time after that.

The value I use to increment is a label text which is dependent on a `UIStepper` value.

Here is the complete function I use to update and increment this value:

```
func paymentAuthorizationViewController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, handler completion: @escaping (PKPaymentAuthorizationResult) -> Void) {
    
    guard let count = guestNumberCount.text else { return }
    guard let labelAsANumber = Int64(count) else { return }
    guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }
    
    let dfmatter = DateFormatter()
    dfmatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM d yyyy, h:mm a"
    let dateFromString = dfmatter.date(from: actualDateOfEvent.text ?? "")
    let dateStamp: TimeInterval = dateFromString!.timeIntervalSince1970
    let dateSt: Int = Int(dateStamp)
    
    
    
    getStudentID { (studid) in
        if let id = studid {
            self.db.document("student_users/\(user.uid)/events_bought/\(self.navigationItem.title!)").setData(["event_name": self.navigationItem.title!, "event_date": self.actualDateOfEvent.text ?? "", "event_cost": self.actualCostOfEvent.text ?? "", "for_grades": self.gradeOfEvent , "school_id": id, "expiresAt":dateSt, "isEventPurchased": true, "time_purchased": Date()], merge: true) { (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("There was an error trying to add purchase info to the database: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("The purchase info was successfully stored to the database!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    getDocumentIDOfSelectedEvent { (eventidentification) in
        if let eventid = eventidentification {
            self.getSchoolDocumentID { (docID) in
                if let doc = docID {
                    self.db.document("school_users/\(doc)/events/\(eventid)/extraEventInfo/TicketCount").updateData(["ticketsPurchased": FieldValue.increment(Int64(labelAsANumber))]) { (error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("There was an error updating the number of tickets: \(error)")
                        } else {
                            print("Number of tickets purchased succesfully updated!")
                            print(labelAsANumber)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.Segues.fromTicketFormToPurchaseDetails, sender: self)
    
    completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationResult(status: .success, errors: []))
}
```

I can't really figure out any issues within the function, neither within my whole project as well in regards to this situation other than the print statement. In the `print(labelAsANumber)` statement, it prints the correct value of the label text (stepper value), but it prints it four times, which is causing the issue. How can I prevent this repetition of print statements and overall incorrect numeric incrementing?

Comment: First, printing a variable doesn't do anything to change its value. However, it could definitely be a *symptom* of the bigger issue. Two questions: 1) Have you set a debugger breakpoint to see what is calling that part of your code multiple times. 2) Are you positive you want to be using `FieldValue.increment` and not just setting the amount to `Int64(labelAsNumber)`?

Comment: I will set a breakpoint and check, but the only way to increment the value in the firestore document in is by using that full `FieldValue.increment()` method, it even it shows it in the  [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value). @jnpdx

Comment: I'm just asking if you truly want to increment it and not just set it to a new value. Your current code will increase it by `labelAsANumber` amount

Comment: Oh yeah no I definitely need to increment it, it's a value I'll need to use in the future. @jnpdx

Comment: You need to figure out why this function is being called so many times and my guess is snapshot listener?